# Cron expression in Spring, validation?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cron

So I need a `Cron` expression which will run my service in following interval:

-`every 2h;`
-`during work hours 9-17h`;
-`only on work days MON-FRI`;
-`every month`;
-`of every year`;

I've come up with this:

```
@Scheduled(* * 0/2 * * MON-FRI)
public Object updateDB() {
    
    controllerImpl.updateDB();
    
    return new Object();
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here s every 2 hours between 9-17h, isn't it?

Try this:

```java
@Scheduled(* * 9-17/2 * * MON-FRI)
```

Comment: As in above comment, service annotated with `@Scheduled(cron="* * 9-17/2 * * MON-FRI", zone="Europe/someCapitalCity")`   is not working

Answer (score 0):

You can try following cron expression:

```
@Scheduled(* * 9-17/2 ? * MON-FRI)
```

For future references you can use following to create your cron expression:
https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. Expression looks correct. I'll test it and once I confirm, I'll upvote you answer.

Comment: If you have tested it, can you please share what does it results in?

Comment: Sorry for the late response bud, well I just set some simple `System,.out::println` just to see will the service be called and it didn't...

Comment: Are you using springboot. If yes, is the class where you have @Scheduled, annotated as @Component?

Comment: The class which contains `@Scheduled` method, is annotated with `@Controller` which is in turn a `@Component`, if I'm not mistaken...And main class has `@EnableScheduling`...